# subprocess.popen seems to fail when run from crontab

Tags: python, cron, subprocess, popen

I'm running a script from crontab that will just ssh and run a command and store the results in a file.

The function that seems to be failing is `subprocess.popen`.

Here is the python function:

```
def _executeSSHCommand(sshcommand,user,node):

    '''
    Simple function to execute an ssh command on a remote node.
    '''

    sshunixcmd = '/usr/bin/ssh %s@%s \'%s\'' % (user,node,sshcommand)
    process = subprocess.Popen([sshunixcmd],
                                shell=True,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait()
    result = process.stdout.readlines()
    return result
```

When it's run from the command line, it executes correctly, from cron it seems to fail with the error message below.

Here are the crontab entries:

`02 * * * *   /home/matt/scripts/check-diskspace.py >> /home/matt/logs/disklog.log`

Here are the errors:

```
Sep 23 17:02:01 timmy CRON[13387]: (matt) CMD (/home/matt/scripts/check-diskspace.py >> /home/matt/logs/disklog.log)
Sep 23 17:02:01 timmy CRON[13386]: (CRON) error (grandchild #13387 failed with exit status 2)
```

I'm going blind trying to find exactly where I have gone so wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your ssh command need any environment variables to work? Remember that cron runs jobs in a pared-down environment with hardly any environment variables defined by default.

Comment: In particular, how is the `ssh` instance intended to authenticate?  If you're using `ssh-agent` then you need to get the necessary environment variables propagated into the cronjob's environment.

Comment: Whenever cron goes wrong, I find redirecting stderr (both in the Popen command and the crontab entry) to a file to gain extra clues about what's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to pass ssh the -i argument to tell ssh to use a specific key file. The problem is that your environment is not set up to tell ssh which key to use.

The fact that you're using python here is a bit of a red herring.

Comment: Hi All, after reading all the comments, I suspect this isn't a python *thing* but rather my lack of understanding around ssh and crontab.

Comment: Thanks to everyone that answered!!! I'll spend this evening hacking about to fill in those knowledge gaps!!!

Answer (score 4):

The cron PATH is very limited. You should either set absolute path to your ssh /usr/bin/ssh or set the PATH as a first line in your crontab.

Answer (score 1):

For everything ssh-related in python, you might consider using [paramiko](http://github.com/robey/paramiko/). Using it, the following code should do what you want.

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(node, username=user)
stdout = client.exec_command(ssh_command)[0]
return stdout.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

When running python scripts from cron, the environment `PATH` can be a hangup, as user1652558 points out.

To expand on this answer with example code to add custom `PATH` values to the environment for a `subprocess` call:

```
import os
import subprocess

#whatever user PATH values you need
my_path = "/some/custom/path1:/some/custom/path2"

#append the custom values to the current PATH settings
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["PATH"] = my_path + ":" + my_env["PATH"]

#subprocess call
resp = subprocess.check_output([cmd], env=my_env, shell=True)
```